# Representation of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ for $\Delta{z} = f_x(a,b)\Delta{x} + f_x(a,b)\Delta{y} + \epsilon_1\Delta{x} + \epsilon_2\Delta{y}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Definition:**

If $z = f(x,y)$, then $f$ is **differentiable** at $(a,b)$ of $\Delta$$z$ can be expressed in the form

$$\Delta{z} = f_x(a,b)\Delta{x} + f_x(a,b)\Delta{y} + \epsilon_1\Delta{x} + \epsilon_2\Delta{y}$$

where $\epsilon_1$and $\epsilon_2$ $\to 0$ as $(\Delta{x},\Delta{y})$ $\to (0,0).$

I know that this is a definition, but is there a geometric picture that can illustrate this definition? I'm having trouble figuring what $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ represent. I know that in one variable functions,

$$
\lim_{\Delta{x}\to0}\epsilon = \lim_{\Delta{x}\to0}(\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}-f^\prime(a))= 0
$$

where

$$\Delta{y} = f(a+\Delta{x})-f(a)$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just like you did, except that for more than one dimension one doesn't divide by $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$ because it is not a number instead $$\lim_{(\Delta x, \Delta y)\to0}\frac{\left|\Delta z - f_x\Delta x-f_y\Delta y\right|}{\left\|(\Delta x, \Delta y)\right\|}=0$$

Comment: In $(X,Y,Z)$, $Z=f_xX+f_yY$ is a plane. So $\Delta z-f_x\Delta x-f_y\Delta y$ is the difference between $\Delta z$ and that plane.

Comment: @OR $f_xX+f_yY$ is a plane -- isn't it the tangent plane? I thought so, but couldn't show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps.

In the figure below, $f(a+\Delta x,b+\Delta y)$ is the 'sum' of the red lines -- ie, sum of $f(a,b),f_x(a,b)\Delta x$ and $f_y(a,b)\Delta y$. The point $P$ is $(a,b,f(a,b))$ and $Q$ is $(a+\Delta x,b+\Delta y,f(a+\Delta x,b+\Delta y))$. "The line with slope $f_x(a,b)$" is the line in the plane $y=b$ passing through $P$ and having 'slope' $f_x(a,b)$. Similarly "the line with slope $f_x(a,b)$" is the line in the plane $x=a$ passing through $P$ and having 'slope' $f_y(a,b)$.

[image: Approximation of $f(a+\Delta x,b+\Delta y)$ is 'sum' of red lines]

Some portion of the image is zoomed below to show how how the red lines have the mentioned values.

[image: The above image zoomed]

From this picture, we cannot say anything about the  error in approximation. (ie, we cannot say the error is $\epsilon_1 \Delta x+\epsilon_2 \Delta y$ where $\epsilon_1\to0$ and $\epsilon_2\to0$ as $(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to0$. This is one of the reasons why the usual approach is to stick to algebra.